# Magnet widget as a child

Tags: python, kivy

About Magnet:
https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.magnet

Here's a working Magnet widget (I changed it a bit)

```py
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ListProperty, DictProperty
from kivy.animation import Animation

class Magnet(Widget):
    transitions = DictProperty({'pos': 'in_out_quad', 'size': 'in_out_quad'})
    duration = NumericProperty(1)
    anims = ListProperty([])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Magnet, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(**{k: self.attract for k in self.transitions})

    def on_children(self, *args):
        if len(self.children) > 1:
            raise ValueError('Magnet can have only one children')
        else:
            self.attract()

    def attract(self, *args):
        if not self.children:
            return

        if self.anims:
            for a in self.anims:
                a.stop(self.children[0])
            self.anims = []

        for t in self.transitions:
            a = Animation(t=self.transitions[t], d=self.duration,
                          **{t: getattr(self, t), })

            a.start(self.children[0])
            self.anims.append(a)
```

I would like to change it to use it not as a parent, but as a child.

I mean:
  default Magnet:

```
Magnet
    SomeWidget
```

Magnet I want to achieve:

```
SomeWidget
    Magnet
```

I tried to implement it simply changing 'children' to 'parent' but this example doesn't work:

```py
class Magnet(Widget):
    transitions = DictProperty({'pos': 'in_out_quad', 'size': 'in_out_quad'})
    duration = NumericProperty(1)
    anims = ListProperty([])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Magnet, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(**{k: self.attract for k in self.transitions})

    def on_parent(self, *args):
        self.attract()

    def attract(self, *args):
        if not self.parent:
            return

        if self.anims:
            for a in self.anims:
                a.stop(self.parent)
            self.anims = []

        for t in self.transitions:
            a = Animation(t=self.transitions[t], d=self.duration,
                          **{t: getattr(self, t), })

            a.start(self.parent)
            self.anims.append(a)
```

What did I miss?

Comment: The `Magnet` widget acts as an invisible container for its one child. When the `Magnet` is moved or resized, it applies those same changes to its child via `Animation`. Typically, those changes are made to the `Magnet` by its parent (like a `Layout` widget). So what is the desired behavior of your proposed `Magnet`?

Comment: I just want to achieve the same behavior that Magnet has, but without need to add a Magnet as a parent widget

Comment: oh I made a mistake in a code that starts right after `Here's a working Magnet widget` (I copypasted wrong source). it could confuse. Fixed now